# split string by tag java

Tags: java, regex, split

I have string

```
stringst...ringstring11<jscript>qweqweqw....eqwe</jscript>22string..string
```

I have to remove everything between the tags

```
stringst...ringstring1122string..string
```

please tell me how to do it

```
String[] split = response.split("\\<jscript\\>");
```

it does not work

Comment: Are the tags guaranteed to be `jscript`? Is the content between the tags user generated, and if so, is it going to be properly escaped?

Comment: This looks to me like it's an attempt to sanitise random HTML. This is a difficult thing to do properly. If I were you, I'd find a nice parsing library and incorporate that, thanking the author profusely for allowing you to ignore the umpteen billion reasons that could cause a custom attempt to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're parsing something like HTML and it is a single `<jscript></jscript>` You could do something like

```
int frontIndex = originalString.IndexOf('<jscript>');
int backIndex =  originalString.IndexOf('</jscript>');

String front = originalString.substring(0,frontIndex); 
String back = originalString.substring(backIndex,originalString.length()); 

originalString = front + back;
```

This will take everything before and up to `<jscript>`, everything after `</jscript>` and until the `string.length()`, then concatenate them together and replace the original string.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex and replaceAll to replace the tags and anything in between them with nothing.

Quick and dirty:

```
str = str.replaceAll("<jscript>[^<]*?</jscript>","");
```

It should be noted this is not a scalable solution and has serious limitations. HTML should not be parsed with regex as a rule, but this is a simple way which works within those limitations.

Limitations:

- Fails if text between tags contains "<"
- Fails if tags are not jscript

Comment: This only works if there are no less-than comparisons, or if there's no use of jQuery DOM element creation, or any number of other reasons.

Comment: Edited to clarify as such. This is not a perfect solution, but for a simple purpose this is much simpler to implement. Added notice of limitations in the hope of avoiding flaming.

Comment: Should probably use the non-greedy version in case there are multiple occurrences of the tag pair: `str = str.replaceAll("<jscript>[^<]*?</jscript>","");`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the old friend apache common. It has [StringUtils.removePattern](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#removePattern%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

**Documentation says**

> public static String removePattern(String source, String regex)
>
> Removes each substring of the source String that matches the given
>   regular expression using the DOTALL option

You can use it in the following way:

```
String result = StringUtils.removePattern(response, "<jscript>[^<]*?</jscript>");
```

It is worth mentioning that parsing html with regex could put you inside a black hole and will decrement your Life expectancy.
Updated: added Robby Cornelissen suggestion