# Match only "<span>something</span>endofline" and not "<span>something</span></span>"

Tags: java, regex

I have a pattern to match something like

```
...
<span class="count">1036</span>
...
```

But I don't want to match

```
<span class="count">1036</span></span>
```

Because it will catch

```
1036</span>
```

But anyway I don't want to catch the double span because I don't need this data.
I need the data between a span and end of line.

I tried with \n at the end of the span but it didn't work...
Here's the pattern:

```
private static final Pattern COUNT = Pattern.compile("<span class=\"count\">(.+?)</span> ");
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: I would change `.+?` which matches anything to `[^<]+` which would match any characters that are not the `<` char. For this solution you must be sure that any inner HTML is encoded - valid `<` are output as `&gt;`. Regex may be a bad solution for this, you can't write regex to match an entire node. Use a HTML parser instead, something like http://jsoup.org/.

Comment: Never use regex to parse html. Use an html parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with grouping feature of regex that is enclosed inside the parenthesis () and get it using `Matcher#group(1)`.

Regex pattern

```
<span class="count">([^<]*?)</span>
```

[DEMO](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xKPqy1mvu1F4lBSa)

Sample code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<span class=\"count\">([^<]*?)</span>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<span class=\"count\">1036</span></span>");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

output:

```
1036
```

Comment: Find similar type of issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124033/split-string-by-tag-java)

Answer (score 0):

The regex code for "end of line" is `$`.

Try:

```
private static final Pattern COUNT = Pattern.compile("<span class=\"count\">(.+?)</span>$ ");
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, the catch group can still match `</span>`.

Comment: Yep you're right, it's definitely going to require negating an opening angle bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Use the multi-line switch `(?m)`, which makes ^ and $ match start/end of line.

```
Pattern COUNT = Pattern.compile("(?m)<span class=\"count\">(.+?)</span>$");
```